# Psalm 20:6 - prophecy who is 'His anointed' that is saved?

Tags: psalms, prophecy

***This and the below are clearly Prophecies*** Psalm 20:6 - Now I know that the LORD saves ***His anointed***; He will answer him from His holy heaven With the saving strength of His right hand.

***Also is Psalm 20:6 connected to the below?***

Luke 24:44  “These are the words which I spoke to you while I was still with you, that all things must be fulfilled which were written in the Law of Moses and the Prophets and the ***Psalms concerning Me***.”

Psalm 9:13 - 13 Have mercy on me, O LORD! Consider my trouble from those who hate me,***You who lift me up from the gates of death,***

Psalm 21:2 - You have given him his heart’s desire, And have ***not withheld the request of his lips.*** Selah

Hebrews 5:7 " Who in the days of his flesh, having offered up prayers and supplications with strong crying and tears unto him that was able to ***save him from death***, and having been heard
for his godly fear."

Psalm 21:13 Be exalted in your strength, ***Lord;*** we will sing and praise your might. PS 22:16 For dogs surround me; a band of evil men encircles me; they have ***pierced my hands and feet.***

Luke 22:44 And being in agony, He prayed more earnestly. Then His sweat became like great drops of blood falling down to the ground.

Psalm 21:4 - He asked life from You, and You gave it to him, Length of days forever and ever. ***His*** (not talking about David)  glory is great in Your salvation; Honor and majesty You have placed upon him.

John 11:41-42 - 41) Then they took away the stone from the place where the dead man was lying. And Jesus lifted up His eyes and said, “Father, I thank You that ***You have heard Me.*** 42) And I know that ***You always hear Me,*** but because of the people who are standing by I said this, that they may believe that You sent Me.”

Comment: that was a quick -1 didn't think it was that bad a question - good to hear any reasons or is it just personal?

Comment: of course it's personal :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Psalm 20:6 is connected to all other prayers of the same kind. But only as an ongoing example of God's saving grace. David was a type of Jesus, as were others from OT days, Joshua, Moses etc. They all had aspects of their lives that Jesus fulfilled on a grander scale and now for ever.

Those that were anointed, like David - a shepherd and King, Joshua a faithful leader, Aaron the Priest, Moses miracles etc, were chosen by God for a special role. They were granted a measure of His Spirit (anointed) to enable their eyes, ears and hearts to be open to God's will and purposes. They were granted wisdom, strength and through God's spirit working with them they saw things more like God did.

> Acts 10:38 God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Spirit. This is quoted from Isaiah 61 and is an example of an OT prophecy finding deeper fulfilment in Christ.

God desires all would be saved. He has laid down the foundation for this in Christ who died to save all men and redeem all creation from evil.

> ...through him (Jesus) to reconcile to Himself all things, whether things on earth or things in heaven, by making peace through his blood, shed on the cross.

David and the prophets understood there was another day, another age, coming that would usher in salvation. Abraham knew God could raise the dead.

Salvation in their day was more physically oriented, wars, pestilence famine, etc and God would see them through - saving them from disaster. So long as they put God first - repenting, offering and sacrifice.

Jesus was no different. As a man only, he needed saving too.

He was anointed with God's spirit - filled with it so that he would be equipped to handle the worst, the darkest, the most evil in the universe.

But he could not ever do it alone. Hence his prayers -

> " Who in the days of his flesh, having offered up prayers and supplications with strong crying and tears unto him that was able to save him from death, and having been heard for his godly fear." Hebrews 5:7

This is not about the hours before the cross. This references the days of his fleshly life - all of it!

**How is the Jesus who died, saved from death?**

Jesus knew the Psalms. He quoted one as he was dying Ps 22. Just the start and the end, 'Why have you forsaken me?' and 'It is finished'. It too speaks of salvation.

He knew he was the anointed one - the Messiah, the one who must die as the Lamb. He also knew as David and all the others, that they were doomed unless God stepped in to save them.

For Jesus, God did save him all his life from the death he would die if he sinned just once! Jesus knew he was not alone and he knew he needed God's spirit to overcome the fleshly tendencies to put his will first. If he did, he would die and not be raised again - and neither would we.

Game over, and not in a good way!

Knowing his limitations, he trusted in God against everything else. His many prayers were heard because of his humility - his Godly fear, his piety as the translations strive to offer the word that reflects his worship and obedience to, and trust of, the Father.

Jesus was perfected and completed - as his brothers will be in him, at his return.

> though being a son, he learned obedience from the things he suffered, 9 and having been perfected, he became the author of eternal salvation to all those obeying him... Heb 5:8

Answer (score 0):

Ps 20, 21, 9 are all Psalms of David (according to their respective superscriptions) in praise to God for His lovingkindness, sustaining power and deliverance from David's enemies.

The "anointed" (Ps 20:6) is David himself as recorded in 2 Sam 2:4, 5:3, 17, 23:1, 1 Chron 14:8, Ps 18:50, 89:20, 132:17, etc.

Heb 5:7 says, "During the days of Jesus’ earthly life, He offered up prayers and petitions with loud cries and tears to the One who could save Him from death, and He was heard because of His reverence."

This is talking about Jesus and is probably an allusion to Jesus prayer in the garden (Matt 26:39)

> Going a little farther, he fell with his face to the ground and
> prayed, "My Father, if it is possible, may this cup be taken from me.
> Yet not as I will, but as you will."

Thus, Jesus asked to be excused from the trial He was about to endure but submitted to the will of God.  I struggle to see a direct connection between this and the psalms quoted by the OP.  I think the question should be clarified as to the point the OP is attempting to make.

Comment: The Ps appear to be prophecies arguably about Jesus - Psalm 21:13 Be exalted in your strength, ***Lord;*** we will sing and praise your might. ***is David Lord*** 22:16 For dogs surround me; a band of evil men encircles me; they have ***pierced my hands and feet.*** does this relate to David?

Comment: another example - about Judah - "For it is written in the Book of Psalms, "'May his camp become desolate, and let there be no one to dwell in it'; and ***let another take his office***."(Acts 1:20).  Ps 109: 7 When he is tried, let him be found guilty, and may his prayers condemn him. 8 May his days be few; ***may another take his place*** of leadership. etc...

Comment: @anothertheory - I fully agree that parts of some of these have been applied to tyhe Messiah in the NT but that does not make all of them about Messiah.

Comment: yes not all are related but there are a lot more added a couple more but did not want too add to many - but clearly David is not talking about himself, its prophecies.